# Error HRESULT 0x80131044 when trying to use csmatio in EA Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, add-in, enterprise-architect

Im trying to create a .mat file in Visual Studio (C#) from data that i get from Enterprise Architect as an Addin. I linked the library in the dependencies and can use it in my code in VS itself, but if I try to execute the Addin in Enterprise Architect i get

`"EA_MenuClick: The assembly "csmatio, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null" or a dependency was not found. An assembly with a strong name is required. (Exception from Error HRESULT 0x80131044)"`

[image]

Since I didnt have this problem (or error Code) with the other dependencies and dlls I use, what are my options to solve this?

Tried to delete and add it in again, didnt solve the problem. When googling the error, I only saw it in an Autodesk Forum where the Addin provider udpated their dll.

Comment: Looks like a problem in the way you are building this dependency. You'll have to add the details on how you reference the csmatio dll. Without that it's basically just guessing.

Comment: I just went to my project->Dependencies->Right click to Add dependency... and then choose the .dll-file from my download path. I found out that if im not signing my project (Not checking "Sign assembly" in Object properties) that it will work without problems.